# Prestashop - product name at product description

Tags: prestashop, placeholder, prestashop-1.7

I believe you can help out finding how I can do one thing in **Prestashop** (1.7), by module or even natively (example: `placeholder`)

I want to show the `product name` (field) within the `product description` when adding/editing a product.

Do you know any module that gives us that?

Answer (score 0):

You need shortCodes

[Buy shortcode for prestashop](https://mypresta.eu/modules/front-office-features/shortcodes.html)